# How to group by within a table that doesn't have attributes that can be grouped on SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, user-defined-functions

I have the following tables:

- Orders
- Products
- OrderDetails as a Joint table.

I also have a Categories table that is connected to Products; CategoryID is a foreign table on Products.

I'm trying to get a table that contains Year of order between 1997, 1998, Quarter, Category Name starting with C letter and Sale(UDF). Here's what I tried:

```
Select YEAR(o.OrderDate) AS "Year", DATENAME(Quarter, o.OrderDate) AS "Qtr",
       c.CategoryName,
       dbo.SaleAfterDiscount(od.UnitPrice, od.Quantity, od.Discount) AS "Sale"
  From Orders o, [Order Details] od, Categories c, Products p
 WHERE (YEAR(o.OrderDate)='1997'OR YEAR(o.OrderDate)='1998')
   AND c.CategoryName LIKE 'c%'
   AND od.OrderID = o.OrderID
   AND od.ProductID = p.ProductID
   AND c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
```

But I get a lot of results. How can I group them or fix the query to get the right answer?

Comment: So what is actually wrong? You are getting all line entries for 1997 and 1998 orders... as expected and described

Comment: @gbn When I run this query, I get 452 rows while I'm supposed to only get 12 records. Do I have to add "Distinct"? Because I don't see any attributes where answers can be grouped by

Comment: Try DISTINCT. What happens?

Comment: You may group by expression if that is what you want: `group by YEAR(o.OrderDate), DATENAME(Quarter, o.OrderDate)` and sum `Sale`.

Comment: @Gbn rows went down to 423.

Comment: @YousifAlmuzayen, you can `group by`, but you need to explain how you want the grouped values to be combined.

Comment: how do you know you're only supposed to get 12 records?

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović, Yes I would like to have them All summed together (Sales for Each quarter)

Comment: @RobJohnson because It's been applied before and I need to prove this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use explicit JOINs
2. Don't use a function on a column
3. GROUP BY all non-aggregated columns

Like this:

```
Select
     YEAR(o.OrderDate) AS "Year",
     DATENAME(Quarter, o.OrderDate) AS "Qtr",
     c.CategoryName,
     SUM(dbo.SaleAfterDiscount(od.UnitPrice, od.Quantity, od.Discount)) AS "SaleSum"
From
     Orders o
     JOIN
     [Order Details] od ON od.OrderID=o.OrderID
     JOIN
     Products p ON od.ProductID=p.ProductID
     JOIN
     Categories c ON c.CategoryID=p.CategoryID
WHERE
     o.OrderDate >= '19970101' AND o.OrderDate < '19990101'
     AND
     c.CategoryName LIKE 'c%'
GROUP BY
     YEAR(o.OrderDate),
     DATENAME(Quarter, o.OrderDate),
     c.CategoryName;
```

Comment: oops! I only needed Sum before my function. That worked just perfect. Thank you so much.